# What are possible pandas basic / scalar data types?

Tags: pandas, numpy

I found the list of NumPy's scalar types: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/user/basics.types.html

I know that pandas adds timestamp types to these. Are there any more types? Is there a comprehensive list of pandas scalar types somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally (and loosely) speaking, pandas columns are just labelled numpy arrays and have comparable dtypes.  The only exception I know of is the pandas categorical type.

Here's an [example dtype listing from the official docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#selecting-columns-based-on-dtype).  Not guaranteed to be exhaustive, but to the best of my knowledge it is pretty close.

```
In [423]: df.dtypes
Out[423]: 
bool1                                   bool
bool2                                   bool
category                            category
dates                         datetime64[ns]
float64                              float64
int64                                  int64
string                                object
uint8                                  uint8
tdeltas                      timedelta64[ns]
uint64                                uint64
other_dates                   datetime64[ns]
tz_aware_dates    datetime64[ns, US/Eastern]
dtype: object
```

Note that the object dtype includes strings and is basically just anything except an int, float, bool, category, or datetime/timedelta.  An object dtype is really just a holder for any generic python type and could be a list, dictionary, etc.

Comment: Note that the list of Pandas dtypes has grown somewhat as they have begun to branch out from Numpy-backed arrays to Arrow-backed arrays, notably `pd.Int64Dtype` and `pd.StringDtype` which have a proper native "null" representation and are "dtype-safe", unlike `object`. There is also support for creating your own custom dtypes: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html

Comment: @shadowtalker yeah, this is out of date, i haven't been keepng up with the latesst pandas advances. feel free to edit or just make your own answer or link to a better answer

Comment: There is still no exhaustive listing, but I figured a mention of the newer dtypes might be helpful for readers.