# How does Pandas determine if something is a "scalar"?

Tags: python, pandas

When I write

```py
data = pd.DataFrame(...)

data['x'] = some_value
```

Pandas tries to be "smart" and implicitly decides whether `some_value` is a "scalar" and should be broadcast, or should be treated as a sequence and should be assigned as a new column without broadcasting.

You see similar checks in functions like `.fillna()` and `.mask()`.

What logic does Pandas use to make this determination, and can this logic be accessed and used by a user? Ideally, I'd like to be able to import and use a function like `pandas.is_scalar()`:

```py
from pandas import is_scalar

assert not is_scalar([1,2,3])
assert not is_scalar({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
assert not is_scalar((3, 4))
assert is_scalar('abcdef')
assert is_scalar(None)
assert is_scalar((i for i in range(6))
```

This question is not the same as [What are possible pandas basic / scalar data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44963503/2954547), which asks about the "fundamental" dtypes that a Series can contain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function exists as [`pd.api.types.is_scalar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.api.types.is_scalar.html):

```
from pandas.api.types import is_scalar 

assert not is_scalar([1,2,3])
assert not is_scalar({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
assert not is_scalar((3, 4))
assert not is_scalar(i for i in range(6))
assert is_scalar('abcdef')
assert is_scalar(None)
assert is_scalar(123)
```

From the docs, here is a list of all objects for which `is_scalar` returns True:

> - numpy array scalar (e.g. np.int64)
> - Python builtin numerics
> - Python builtin byte arrays and strings
> - None
> - datetime.datetime
> - datetime.timedelta
> - Period
> - decimal.Decimal
> - Interval
> - DateOffset
> - Fraction
> - Number

The `pd.api.types` submodule also has other helper functions to specifically check for the type of certain objects (such as arrays, dicts, complex numbers, etc).